# How to trap signal on ruby running on windows

Tags: windows, ruby

How to trap signal on ruby running on windows?

I want to send signal/message from C++ application to ruby script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal.list tells you which ones are supported on your system

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [Signal Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Signal.html). The documentation has a pretty good example at the very top.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the signal. If you want to trap ctrl-C, that works in Windows. Many signals (sigup1, sigusr1, etc) don't really work right in Windows (at least not for me). Here's how to trap ctrl-C. In this example, I'm just printing a message and then exiting the application. You could pass any proc object to the signal manager -- be sure you pay attention to scope, if you read/edit variables inside the proc:

```
trap("INT") { puts "\nExiting"; exit;}
```